# Access control at property level (hiding/showing properties in api response based on the role)

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, keycloak

I have a spring-boot based micro-service generated using JHipster.

I am using **keycloak** as my Auth Server. I could enable Role-based & scope based authorization on my resources(apis).

Now the requirement is:  based on the role of the client, I need to restrict the information to send in the response (either mask the attributes or nullify them). 
eg: 
consider the following api to get the person's profile

**/api/person/{id}**

```
{
  "name": {
    "firstName": "Jack",
    "lastName": "Sparrow"
  },
  "gender": "MALE",
  "emails": {
    "details": [
      {
        "emailId": "jack.sparrow@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "phones": {
    "details": [
      {
        "phoneNumber": "1234567890",
        "countryCode": "+1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "addresses": {
    "details": [
      {
        "addressLine1": "aaaaaaaa",
        "addressLine2": "bbbbbbb",
        "city": "cccccc",
        "state": "ddddd",
        "country": "South Africa",
        "postalCode": "987654"
      }
    ]
  },
  "photo": "string",
  "nationality": "South Africa",
  "countryOfResidence": "string",
  "active": true,
  "createdAt": 1537431339569,
  "modifiedAt": 1537436600693,
  "createdBy": "admin",
  "modifiedBy": "admin"
}
```

Now, when a person with **BASIC** role calls this API, the requirement is to show only basic information like:
- name, gender

If he has **INTERMEDIATE** role then we can send something more than basic but not full information. eg: name, gender, photo, nationality

If he has **ADMIN** role then we can send the complete information.

Can anyone please let me know What is the best approach to achieve this.

-- Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It can't be done in Keycloak without modifying your app. Have you considered using JHipster DTO option and customizing generated mapper?

Comment: Are you referring to map-struct?

Comment: yes but you would copy mapstruct generated mapper from target to src and then customize it and then disable mapstruct

Comment: will mapper have some constructs to handle roles? I am looking for some annotation based way of hiding/showing rather than writing code

Comment: No. Even spring security annotations would not help here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/authorization.html#method-security-expressions

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution for this?

Comment: We ended up writing custom code to nullify the attributes based on annotations (custom)